# Flutter: Location permission: when in use or always

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to know if the user has selected "only when in use" or "always" for the location.

https://pub.dev/packages/location_permissions

I tried this code from the package:

```
 ServiceStatus serviceStatus =
          await LocationPermissions().checkServiceStatus();
      print(serviceStatus);
```

But it prints:

```
ServiceStatus.enabled
```

Is there a possibility (perhaps with another package) to know this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this package will give you the status in `denied`, `granted`, `restricted` and `unknown`. You can read through the enum section.

Comment: I tried but it gives : 'granted' in both cases

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) can do this.

```dart
enum PermissionGroup {
  ...

  /// Android: Fine and Coarse Location
  /// iOS: CoreLocation - Always
  locationAlways,

  /// Android: Fine and Coarse Location
  /// iOS: CoreLocation - WhenInUse
  locationWhenInUse
}
```

Requesting permissions:

```dart
final ph = PermissionHandler();
final requested = await ph.requestPermissions([
  PermissionGroup.locationAlways, 
  PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse
]);

final alwaysGranted = requested[PermissionGroup.locationAlways] == PermissionStatus.granted;
final whenInUseGranted = requested[PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse] == PermissionStatus.granted;
```

Add these permissions to AndroidManifest.xml inside `<manifest>` tag:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test_project">

    <!-- add these -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
...
```

And these to `<dict>` tag of Info.plist:

```xml
    <!-- Permission options for the `location` group -->
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Need location when in use</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Always and when in use!</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Older devices need location.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Can I haz location always?</string>
```

Comment: Thanks! I already added it, so I don't know if this can be the problem....

Comment: Yes, so I asked the permission earlier. Within the app, I want to know if the permission is set to 'always' to show a certain screen. But I  keep getting false for both values....

Comment: Don't use this library for iOS. Your app might be rejected by apple for requesting too many permissions. Look at github issues for solution.

Comment: Use await Permission.locationAlways.request() after installing permission_handler package

Answer (score 2):

This library is support Stream so you can check like that.

```
 LocationPermissions().serviceStatus.listen((event) {
    if(event == ServiceStatus.disabled){
      print('Location Disabled');
      }else{
      print('Location Enabled');
     });
```

Good luck.

Comment: This answer is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Geolocator package may be used for that. From its readMe page:

> This method returns a value of the GeolocationStatus enum indicating
> the availability of the location services on the device. Optionally
> you can specify if you want to test for
> GeolocationPermission.locationAlways or
> GeolocationPermission.locationWhenInUse

. Have a look here - https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator