# location in real time with flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to capture the latitude and longitude in real time with my gps on my device however so far I am only getting the current longitude and latitude and it is not updating.

What I want to do is that when the gps detects that the latitude or longitude has changed, they are updated on the screen

additionally it is happening to me that when I start if I start the application and deny the permission the application breaks

For this exercise I am using geolocator: ^ 5.3.2 + 2 I appreciate your help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrtDY.png)

Error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fgl3.png)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  String _locationMessage = "";

  Future disponiblidad() async {
    var geoLocator = Geolocator();
    var status = await geoLocator.checkGeolocationPermissionStatus();

    if (status == GeolocationStatus.denied) {
      //pedirpermiso();
      // Llevar a la usuario a la configuración de permisos
      print('Llevar a la usuario a la configuración de permisos');
    } else if (status == GeolocationStatus.disabled) {
      //AppSettings.openLocationSettings();

      //Llevar a la usuario a la página de ubicación
      print('Llevar a la usuario a la página de ubicación');
    } else if (status == GeolocationStatus.restricted) {
      // Restringida
      print('Restringida');
    } else if (status == GeolocationStatus.unknown) {
      // Desconocida
      print('Desconocida');
    } else if (status == GeolocationStatus.granted) {
      //Permiso otorgado y ubicación habilitada
      print('Permiso otorgado');
      location();
    }
  }

  void pedirpermiso() async {
    final position = await Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    if (position == null) {}
  }

  void location() async {
    var geolocator = Geolocator();
    var locationOptions =
        LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, distanceFilter: 10);

    // ignore: unused_local_variable
    // ignore: cancel_subscriptions
    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = geolocator
        .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
        .listen((Position position) {
      setState(() {
        print(position == null
            ? 'Unknown'
            : position.latitude.toString() +
                ', ' +
                position.longitude.toString());
        _locationMessage =
            "${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}";

        //String hoa = positionStream;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // _checkGps();
    disponiblidad();
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Location Services")),
            body: Align(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_locationMessage),
                    FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          // _getCurrentLocation();
                        },
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Text("Find Location"))
                  ]),
            )));
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680190/flutter-location-permission-when-in-use-or-always) there is a simple example on how to check if the permissions are granted.
The Geolocator package has some great examples on their repo, for a continuous location check [this example](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/blob/develop/example/lib/pages/location_stream_widget.dart)

Answer (score 1):

You may use a stream object for this purpose. The geolocator package offers such an api which continuesly listen for changes.

Here is one example:

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

var geolocator = Geolocator();
var locationOptions = LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, 
                      distanceFilter: 10);

StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = geolocator
                                .getPositionStream(locationOptions)
                                .listen((Position position) {
    print(position == null ? 'Unknown' : position.latitude.toString() + ', ' + 
       position.longitude.toString());
});
```

Using this in combination with a StreamBuilder widget (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) you should be able to reflect any position updates to the ui.

Comment: this works for me but if I deny permission it stops

Comment: sounds reasonable, if you dont have location permission, you cannot track the users location, this is expected behavior, isnt it ?

Comment: In the description attach the image of the error: Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(PERMISSION_DENIED, Access to location data denied, null))

Comment: Did you extend your platform config files for requesting permission? Or did you manually denied the permission ? In the latter case, this error is reasonabe and you need to catch it and maybe show some alert to the user.
If you did not modify the config files, please do so by following the steps described here: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#permissions

Comment: I already assigned the permissions to which it refers, however the error persists.

Comment: Do you use an emulator or a physical device ?