# Flutter iOS webview app with Geolocation website doesn't Ask For Location Permission even info.plist is adjusted

Tags: ios, flutter, webview, permissions, geolocation

I am trying to make a webview app with a website which needs location permission to use geolocation javascript. I tried something on swift side to enable but unfortunately couldn't manage it. [wkwebview-app-doesnt-ask-for-location-permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236807/wkwebview-app-doesnt-ask-for-location-and-gallery-permission)

On flutter side, I have enabled geolocation and javascript by using [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) I have added same stuff to info.plist. What I have to do more to get permission and enable location for website? Thanks in advance

```
  child: WebviewScaffold(
            //mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: true,
            debuggingEnabled: true,
            url: 'https://nakliyemvar.com/isveren/giris.php',
            scrollBar: false,
            //hidden: true,
            withZoom: false,
            withJavascript: true,
            geolocationEnabled: true,


            //withLocalUrl: true,
            appCacheEnabled: true,
          ),
```

info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>asd</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>asd.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check location authorization status on Swift side and if not determined you need to request it before opening the webview. Something like this:

```
private func manageLocationPermission() {
    let authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .notDetermined:
        CLLocationManager().requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
       // Open the webview
    case .denied:
       // Notify the user about it
    case .restricted:
       break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it more likely a solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68236807/wkwebview-app-doesnt-ask-for-location-and-gallery-permission How can I integrate it with my code?

Comment: Check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680190/flutter-location-permission-when-in-use-or-always Is this answer your question?