# Flutter send location when screen is locked

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator, location, android-gps

I'm developing a GPS tracking app by using [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location).
I've wrapped the intervals function to send latitude and longitude in API. It works on an emulator when the screen is locked and stay on home screen

```
  void _startInterval() {
   timerInterval = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
     _sendLocation(); // Send location to api
   });
  }
```

So when I'm building the APK to my device my application cannot send the location.
Is there any way to send the location the same as the Emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you dont have set the Permissons.

Add these permissions to AndroidManifest.xml inside  tag:

```
<!-- add these -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

...

And these to  tag of Info.plist:

```
<!-- Permission options for the `location` group -->
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Need location when in use</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Always and when in use!</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Older devices need location.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can I haz location always?</string>
```

[Topic in another Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680190/flutter-location-permission-when-in-use-or-always)

Comment: I've got these options on my AndroidManifest file 

Answer (score 0):

you have to add permissions

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

you need to import flutter package

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  geolocator: ^8.0.0
```

Example code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Home()
    );
  }
}

class Home extends  StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  bool servicestatus = false;
  bool haspermission = false;
  late LocationPermission permission;
  late Position position;
  String long = "", lat = "";
  late StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkGps();
    super.initState();
  }

  checkGps() async {
    servicestatus = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if(servicestatus){
      permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
        if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
          print('Location permissions are denied');
        }else if(permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever){
          print("'Location permissions are permanently denied");
        }else{
          haspermission = true;
        }
      }else{
        haspermission = true;
      }

      if(haspermission){
        setState(() {
          //refresh the UI
        });

        getLocation();
      }
    }else{
      print("GPS Service is not enabled, turn on GPS location");
    }

    setState(() {
      //refresh the UI
    });
  }

  getLocation() async {
    position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    print(position.longitude); //Output: 80.24599079
    print(position.latitude); //Output: 29.6593457

    long = position.longitude.toString();
    lat = position.latitude.toString();

    setState(() {
      //refresh UI
    });

    LocationSettings locationSettings = LocationSettings(
      accuracy: LocationAccuracy.high, //accuracy of the location data
      distanceFilter: 100, //minimum distance (measured in meters) a
      //device must move horizontally before an update event is generated;
    );

    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream = Geolocator.getPositionStream(
        locationSettings: locationSettings).listen((Position position) {
      print(position.longitude); //Output: 80.24599079
      print(position.latitude); //Output: 29.6593457

      long = position.longitude.toString();
      lat = position.latitude.toString();

      setState(() {
        //refresh UI on update
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Get GPS Location"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent
        ),
        body: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
            child: Column(
                children: [

                  Text(servicestatus? "GPS is Enabled": "GPS is disabled."),
                  Text(haspermission? "GPS is Enabled": "GPS is disabled."),

                  Text("Longitude: $long", style:TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  Text("Latitude: $lat", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),)

                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Now I build your code to my device the problem cannot solve.

Comment: which device are you using?

Comment: I'm using Huawei Y9 2019

Comment: Yes, It's a problem with Huawei phones so you can use add this line.

Comment: Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(forceAndroidLocationManager: true);