# Send geolocation in background on request

Tags: flutter, firebase, geolocation

Perhaps someone had a similar case.
My application needs to track the geolocation of the driver, every half an hour or on request. All this needs to be done in the background. In order to send a position every half hour, I found a solution like [Flutter send location when screen is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717983/flutter-send-location-when-screen-is-locked).
But how can I make it so that I can send my location on request (push). That is, a notification comes through Firebase that the driver needs to send coordinates, respectively, in _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler I will have to send my coordinates to the server. Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to [receive a background message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#background_messages) from FCM, and then how to write to [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/read-and-write) or [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)? If so, these links and the one you shared already should be plenty to get you started.