# Redmi Note 7 doesn't list down flutter Apps

Tags: flutter, google-maps, location, redmi-device

I am working on smart plantation application on flutter, and my emulator is my redmi note 7.
Issue is I want to enable location permission via my mobile device but when I go to the app list, it shows every app but not flutter applications.

[image: Screenshot of mobile screen]

Is there any setting needed to make my app appear on this list?

Comment: Permission added in android manifest file?

Comment: tell me how to?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680190/flutter-location-permission-when-in-use-or-always